# Translation with string format at import time

Tags: django, django-i18n

I have model with attribute like this:

```
new = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_("Is new"),
help_text=_("By default product is marked as new by {0} days since creation.")
.format(settings.PRODUCT_IS_NEW_EXPIRATION_DAYS))
```

This unfortunately works for runserver command but when I want to run test it failes and I receive following error:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.

This error is clear. I'm trying to use translations before apps are ready.

It is possible to have a translation that requires string formatting at import time?

Edit:
Traceback:

```
File "./manage.py", line 9, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
django.setup()
File "django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "haystack/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
signal_processor_class = loading.import_class(signal_processor_path)
File "haystack/utils/loading.py", line 32, in import_class
module_itself = importlib.import_module(module_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "utils/signals.py", line 12, in <module>
from products.models import Products
File "products/models/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .carousel import ProductCarousel, ProductCarouselImage
File "products/models/carousel.py", line 10, in <module>
from products.models.product import Products
File "products/models/product.py", line 210, in <module>
class Products(models.Model):
File "products/models/product.py", line 241, in Products
help_text=(ugettext("By default product is marked as new by {0} days since creation.")).format(
File "django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 84, in ugettext
return _trans.ugettext(message)
File "django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 330, in ugettext
return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
File "django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 307, in do_translate
_default = _default or translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
File "django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 209, in translation
_translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
File "django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 118, in __init__
self._add_installed_apps_translations()
File "django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _add_installed_apps_translations
"The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.
```

Comment: Is this using `ugettext` or `ugettext_lazy`?

Comment: There is no difference if it is  `ugettext` or `ugettext_lazy`. Same error.

Comment: I was hoping that the lazy proxy object's format would have handled this.. I've edited your question to hopefully make it clearer, please feel free to roll back if you feel this is incorrect

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `_("By default product is marked as new by %d days since creation.") % settings.PRODUCT_IS_NEW_EXPIRATION_DAYS` work?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment on the post but I can't since I don't have enough reputation.  Have you tried formatting the help_text first and then translating it?  Something like this:

```
help_text = _(
    "By default product is marked as new by {} days since creation.".format(
        settings.PRODUCT_IS_NEW_EXPIRATION_DAYS
    )
)
new = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_("Is new"),
    help_text=help_text)
```

**NOTE:** .format is inside the ugettext

Comment: Here is the problem that you cant do that. While compilation the `settings.PRODUCT_IS_NEW_EXPIRATION_DAYS` will be paste to this string. In next step when Django is trying to translate it and it will fail because django will be unable to find msgid "By default product is marked as new by 90 days since creation." ( Correct id is "By default product is marked as new by {} days since creation."